# Right align WPF window title

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, interop, styles

I'm currently creating a WPF `Exception Window`, much in the style of the `MessageBox` (static show methods). In attempting to `Style` it similarly, I have created an `ExceptionWindowOptions` enum which contains the value, `RightAlign`.

When the `RightAlign` flag is tagged in the `MessageBox` class, the window title is aligned to the right (next to the control box (minimize, max, close)), so i'm attempting to emulate this behaviour.

I have investigated as much as possible and I cannot find a WPF solution.

I am familiar with interop with native methods as I am using `GetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLong` for the `RtlReading` option, but I haven't managed to find anything to change the location of the window title.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you already are doing such things..... make it better than MessageBox, and instead of one huge ugly enum, add a boolean parameter isRightToLeft..... and keep to that methodology.

Comment: There is a number of other options that can be set (and multi-set via bitwise operations). My intention was to emulate as much of MessageBox's external interface as possible, as to increase the familiarity.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [FluidKit library](http://www.codeplex.com/fluidkit) from Pavan Podila. Particularly, you may be interested in GlassWindow. The main idea here is that you override window style from scratch. Sure, this requires you to customize style for different themes, but at least it's a solution, if you don't find anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to set [Window.FlowDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.flowdirection.aspx).  That will set it for all content in the window however, including buttons, text boxes, etc, so if you ONLY want to make the title bar RTL, you could then have the window contain a panel which would reset it to LTR (or whatever).

Ack- on testing this, maybe not.  It looks like it RTL's ALL of the title bar, including the control box and the icon!

Comment: Yeah, as you've hinted, this isn't a great solution. It send me down the wrong path so I downvoted